# Gradle doesn't build Java Path in Eclipse on Mac when using openjfx plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, javafx

When I import any Gradle-Project with an openjfx plugin the resulting Project does not include a Java Build Path or any Java Libraries. To be honest I'm not sure if this is a Software or Code problem.

I tried to build the Gradle-Task per Terminal and that worked. But I have to use Eclipse, because university. I updated Eclipse to 2019-06 and I reinstalled it. The project uses Openjfx version 0.0.7.
Following the Gradle-Build. As this is part of a exercise others using Windows and the same Gradle-Build didn't have the same problem. 
And the ones using Mac solved it by reinstalling Eclipse.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

}

javafx {
    modules = ['javafx.base', 'javafx.controls']
}

mainClassName = 'javafx.echo.Main'
```

Edit:
[Screenshot of the Properties Menue of the Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ihX7.png)

Comment: Hard to say what could be wrong without more details. Does Eclipse recognizes the Gradle project? There is an option for that, once you have it opened.

Comment: I guess it does recognise it, when I open Properties on the Projcect it shows the Gradle Option and in the Builders Option it shows the "Gradle Project Builder". But not the Java Builder that is normally included.